# Run a ruby script automatically after modification

Tags: ruby, reloading

When I develop in node.js, I like to use [node-supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor) because when I save a file, it reloads automatically, which eliminates the need of having to kill and restart the service every time.

Is there something similar for ruby? Hopefully something easy to install like a gemfile?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like Guard may help.

- [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/264-guard)
- [Gem](https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/List-of-available-Guards)

Answer (score 1):

In this very basic scenario (assuming you have node and npm installed). You can initialize npm via `npm init` and install `nodemon` via `npm i --save nodemon`. Then just, run `npx nodemon --exec "ruby" <path-to-file>/<file-name>.rb`. Hope it help someone to start with!

Answer (score 0):

For Rails server or other Ruby things, you can use [Pow](http://pow.cx)